# Как перехватить данные в Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rxjava

```
public interface IApiRequest {
    String urlDocs="***";

    @GET("***")
    Observable<List<Place>> getPlace(
            @Query("test") int test
    );
}




public class ApiRequest {
    private static IApiRequest init(){
        Retrofit retrofit= new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("***")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
        return retrofit.create(IApiRequest.class);
    }

    public static Observable<List<Place>> getPlace(int test){
        return init().getPlace(test);
    }
}
```

Я использую Rx + Retrofit. Подскажите как мне перехватить данные, чтобы можно было сократить полученный код. Типо JsonObject.getString("***").

так как единственный вариант который в голову мне приходит, это пердавать в `IApiRequest  Response вместо List<Place>`

Разве нет более правильного способа?

### UPDATE

```
public class ApiRequest {
    private static IApiRequest init(int st){
        Gson gson=new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Place.class, (JsonDeserializer<Place>) (json, typeOfT, context) -> {
                    Log.e("ApiRequest=init", "Test" + "");
                    JsonElement jsonElement=json.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("data");
                    return new Gson().fromJson(jsonElement,Place.class);
                }).create();

        Retrofit retrofit= new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("***")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
//                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();

        IApiRequest iApiRequest=retrofit.create(IApiRequest.class);
        Call<ResponseBody> placeCall= iApiRequest.getPlace(st);
        placeCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                try {
                    Log.e("ApiRequest=onResponse", response.body().string() +"");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("ApiRequest=onFailure", t.getMessage() + "");
            }
        });

        return retrofit.create(IApiRequest.class);
    }

    public static IApiRequest getPlace(int startFrom){
        return init(startFrom);
    }
}



public class Place {

    @SerializedName("id") private int id;
    @SerializedName("name") private String name;
    @SerializedName("lat") private double lat;
    @SerializedName("lng") private double lng;
    @SerializedName("categoryId") private int categoryId;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public double getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public int getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }
}
```

`registerTypeAdapter` не вызывается. Что делать?

Comment: МОжете создать кастомную ConverterFactory

Comment: А если у каждого запроса своя структура Json. Что штук 100 таких Converterов создавать чтоли?

Comment: Вы уж определитесь, вам надо десериализовать на лету или сырой JSON получать. А сейчас получается, что вы сначала GSON подключили, а потом спрашиваете "как же мне его обойти"

Comment: Мне нужно получить GSON но переделав Json и получить из запроса только данные из data. исключив response.

И так для 20 запросов. Странно то что разработчикик Retrofit не позаботились об этом. Ведь это заядлая тема и каждый сталкивался с такой проблеммой

Comment: Ну так и напишите одну кастомную фабрику, которая первой командой будет извлекать необходимую подветкой, а второй - отдавать ее стандартной фабрике

Comment: @rjhdby не будет ли у вас на примете примера? или ссылки на гитхаб. Так как думаю не хватит мне знаний реализовать это.

Comment: @rjhdby, может павильно будет как - то использовать 
`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()` и передать его в фабрику? и а не писать свою....

Comment: да, конечно можно и так

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014674/gson-custom-deseralizer-for-one-variable-in-an-object

Comment: @rjhdby, `registerTypeAdapter` не вызывается. Что делать? Я замучился уже